# How to add alchemy to existing spree project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, spree-auth-devise, alchemy-cms, alchemy-spree

I have an existing [Spree](https://github.com/spree/spree) project that is functioning. I'm not try to include [Alchemy CMS](https://github.com/AlchemyCMS/alchemy_cms) in the project. I followed the guide on the Github Repo. The only exception is that I skipped the auth step because I already have [spree_auth_devise](https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise) configured. When trying to install Alchemy, `bundle exec rake alchemy:install`. I get the error below.

#### error

```
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'alchemy_spree'.
/Users/atbyrd/dev/distinct-existence/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/atbyrd/dev/distinct-existence/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/Users/atbyrd/dev/distinct-existence/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
NameError: uninitialized constant Alchemy::AuthEngine
/Users/atbyrd/dev/distinct-existence/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/atbyrd/dev/distinct-existence/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/Users/atbyrd/dev/distinct-existence/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

#### Gemfile

```
ruby '2.2.4'
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'active_model_serializers'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise'
gem 'puma'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'

gem 'alchemy_spree'
gem 'alchemy_cms'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

#### config/initializers/alchemy.rb

```
# Tell Alchemy to use the Spree::User class
Alchemy.user_class_name = 'Spree::User'
Alchemy.current_user_method = :spree_current_user

# Load the Spree.user_class decorator for Alchemy roles
require 'alchemy/spree/spree_user_decorator'

# Include the Spree controller helpers to render the
# alchemy pages within the default Spree layout
Alchemy::BaseHelper.send :include, Spree::BaseHelper
Alchemy::BaseController.send :include, Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Common
Alchemy::BaseController.send :include, Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Store
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like outdated gem versions. Which version of Spree are you using? Please check your `Gemfile.lock`. If it's 3.x then please try to use the GitHub version of this gem by using `gem 'alchemy_spree', github: 'magiclabs/alchemy_spree', branch: 'master'` in your `Gemfile` and run `bundle update alchemy_spree`.

And, regarding to the README you need to add an initializer into your app, if you use `spree_auth_devise`. Just skipping this step will not work.

Everything I mentioned above is stated right in the README of the project. Did you follow it?